# Create a function with a generic input in Java (different potential inputs with same function names)

Tags: java, generics

I am quite new to Java and read about the generic inputs and classes. I was wondering if we can have a function for example named as `getNewWeights(genericInput)` where the `genericInput` can be different class types but they have similar functions, as follows:

```java
public static Double getNewWeight(Class<T> genericInput) {
    double weight = 0.0;
    //logic
    weight = genericInput.getCalcuatedWeight(INPUTS); 
    //logic
    return weight
}
```

while genericInputs of any type has same `getCalcuatedWeight` function.

for example:
if `genericInput` class type is Car or Train both of these classes have a public function as `getCalcuatedWeight` that returns a double value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no dependency between classes then your only options are either reflections as mentioned by @markspace in a comment or using Object as the parameter and casting to a real class like this:

```
public static Double getNewWeight(Object genericInput) {
    double weight = 0.0;
    //logic
    if (genericInput instanceof Car)
        weight = ((Car)genericInput).getCalcuatedWeight(INPUTS);
    else if (genericInput instanceof Train)
        weight = ((Train)genericInput).getCalcuatedWeight(INPUTS);
    //logic
    return weight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, this example is probably not generic.  Instead, use inheritance.  Define an interface with a method `getCalcuatedWeight()` and implement this in all required classes.

```
public interface Weighted {
   float getCalcuatedWeight();
}

public class Car implements Weighted {
   public float getCalcuatedWeight() {
     return 42f;
   }
}

public class Train implements Weighted {
   public float getCalcuatedWeight() {
      return 4200f;
   }
}
```

Comment: so technically what you say is we only can use  `genericInput.getCalcuatedWeight(INPUTS)` if all potential genericInput classes are  childs of the same parent class to use the same function? in your example, the parent is class is `Weighted`... otherwise two independent classes cannot access the same function through a generic clss

Comment: You could, but it gets weird.  Also I'm saying your example doesn't seem to require generics.  It feels better with regular inheritance.  But if you embellish your question more there might be other problems that favor generics.

Comment: The issue is, there is already the public function in use which accepts a specific class type... what i want to do, potentially, is reuse the same function and only make the input to be a generic object

Comment: So this is a function in a source base you control?  If you could show the actual code I think it would help.  Right now, I'd still use inheritance.

Comment: I may not be able to share the actual code, but the code is pretty similar to what i share. The function `getNewWeight` is public as part of a utility class. I am trying to reuse the same utility function but with different type of input class. These input classes can have the same function names (e.g. `getCalcuatedWeight`) while they are independent classes (no inheritance or etc.)

Comment: Well, you can't call methods on a class just because it's generic.  You'd still need the Weighted interface and all the classes would need to implement it, even with generics.  Unless you want to resort to reflection.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here doesn't require generics at all. The object you pass in must implement `getCalcuatedWeight()`, so the way to do that in Java is to define an interface, e.g:

```
interface WeightCalculator {
    double getCalculatedWeight(INPUTS);
}
```

Your method declaration then looks like this:

```
public static Double getNewWeight(WeightCalculator genericInput) {
    ...
}
```

The class of any object you pass to your method must declare that it `implements WeightCalculator`. The compiler will ensure that you have the method defined in your class, and will ensure only a class that implements that interface can be passed to the method.

You could also declare an abstract WeightCalculator class, and have your objects inherit from that, but I think that misrepresents the relationship they have (no hierarchy), and doesn't have any advantage (e.g shared code).